# Manually installing wordpress on Godaddy, system cannot find the path specified

Tags: mysql, wordpress, installation, cyberduck

I am manually installing wordpress on a client's godaddy account. The client has requested I do not install it in the root folder, so it is has been uploaded via cyberduck in it's original wordpress folder. I created a MySQL database and changed the config_sample.php to config.php with all the appropriate information (database username and password).

I cannot complete the final step of the installation. When I go to website.com/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php it says "system cannot find the path specified". I think the website recognizes that wordpress is there somewhere because it is not a "missing page" message, but I'm not really sure what is the problem.

Is there something I need to do to the godaddy account to make it work? Or can wordpress only be installed in the root folder? Or does the IIS need to be updated to IIS7? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'd bet it was the path to the database needs some crazy url coded into the config.php

Comment: Please reply for this question, I have the same error.